Problem with back navigation in Jetpack Compose App
The navigation for my app is defined as follows. It contains three screens. The start destination is the Home screen and the user can navigate to the Add Student Screen by pressing the floating action button.
@Composable
fun SampleRoomApp(
    appViewModel: AppViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            AppTopBar(navController = navController)
        },

        floatingActionButton = {
            ExtendedFloatingActionButton(onClick = { navController.navigate(AppDestinations.ADD_STUDENT.name) }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add,
                    contentDescription = "Add New Student",
                    modifier = Modifier.size(28.dp)
                )

                Text(text = "Add Student")
            }
        },

        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,

        modifier = modifier

    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            startDestination = AppDestinations.HOME.name,
            navController = navController,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(route = AppDestinations.HOME.name) {
                //
            }

            composable(
                route = AppDestinations.STUDENT_DETAILS.name + "\\{$idArgument}",
                arguments = listOf(navArgument(idArgument) { type = NavType.IntType })
            ) { backStackEntry ->
                //
            }

            composable(route = AppDestinations.ADD_STUDENT.name) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppTopBar(
    navController: NavController,
) {
    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
        title = { Text("Sample Room App") },
        navigationIcon = {
            //???
            if (navController.previousBackStackEntry != null) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { navController.navigateUp() },
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "Go Back"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

According to my app logic, the arrowback button should appear when I move to a different screen from the home screen. But this does not happen when I click the FAB. Please help me.

The issue happens because the AppTopBar doesn't recompose when you navigate to a new screen. To fix this, you can use a state variable to trigger recomposition whenever the screen changes.
Here's an updated version of your code that uses a showBackButton state variable:
@Composable
fun SampleRoomApp(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    var showBackButton by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            AppTopBar(
                showBackButton = showBackButton,
                onBack = { navController.navigateUp() }
            )
        },

        floatingActionButton = {
            ExtendedFloatingActionButton(onClick = { navController.navigate(AppDestinations.ADD_STUDENT.name) }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add,
                    contentDescription = "Add New Student",
                    modifier = Modifier.size(28.dp)
                )

                Text(text = "Add Student")
            }
        },

        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,

        modifier = modifier

    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            startDestination = AppDestinations.HOME.name,
            navController = navController,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(route = AppDestinations.HOME.name) {
                showBackButton = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null
            }

            composable(
                route = AppDestinations.STUDENT_DETAILS.name + "\\{$idArgument}",
                arguments = listOf(navArgument(idArgument) { type = NavType.IntType })
            ) { backStackEntry ->
                showBackButton = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null
            }

            composable(route = AppDestinations.ADD_STUDENT.name) {
                showBackButton = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppTopBar(
    showBackButton: Boolean = false,
    onBack: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
        title = { Text("Sample Room App") },
        navigationIcon = {
            //???
            if (showBackButton) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = onBack,
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "Go Back"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

